# Internal macbook pro microphone not working on any browser, but working in apps (skype, slack, photo booth)

Tags: macos, audio, google-chrome, microphone

Specs:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- macOS Mojave v10.14.2
- chrome version  71.0.3578.98
- safari version 12.0.2

Using [this](https://www.onlinemictest.com/) website I can see the line but it isn't moving. The problem occurs on both chrome and safari. However, in safari the line doesn't even appear.

- My google chrome settings are set properly (i.e. allow on request and no sites blocked)
- I have attached a screenshot of my sound input settings
- I have tried installing and uninstalling chrome
- Microphone works fine on photo booth, skype and slack

[image]

Comment: Did you allow access to the mic for the page you're accessing?

Comment: @fsb yes I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome wasn't allowed to use my microphone from the security settings in MacOS. Maybe this setting was lost after the update to Mojave?

1. Goto 'System preferences'
2. Click on 'Security & Privacy'
3. Click on the tab 'Privacy'
4. Select 'Microphone' from the left sidebar
5. Make sure 'Google Chrome' is checked
6. Let's celebrate, it's working again

Comment: Unfortunately chrome isn't in the list for me :/

Comment: This security setting is new in Mojave, which is why you started having the problem after updating to Mojave.

Comment: @crgarridos Check out [How do I configure Camera and Microphone permission on macOS Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384310/18101)

Comment: Thanks @Nic It wasn't that, but thanks to you I remember I had SIP enabled. disabling it did the job ! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I was months looking for a solution and anone of them worked for me. Apps simply didn't ask for permission. Then I remembered that I had disabled [SIP](https://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html)(System Integrity Protection). Re-enabling does the job!

---

Check if SIP is disabled:

```
$ csrutil status
```

If you get `System Integrity Protection status: disabled`. We have to re-enable it.

Restart your Mac in recovery mode:

> Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.

In recovery mode, Utilities menu, select Terminal and execute:

```
$ csrutil enable
$ csrutil clear
```

Reboot and the apps should ask again for every permission.