# How do I reset Camera and Microphone permission on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, system-settings, camera, microphone

I'm using macOS Mojave and I want to use my camera and microphone to make a New Movie Recording in QuickTime Player. But when I try it gives me this error.

> QuickTime Player is not authorized to access the microphone.

I looked in System Preferences but the list is empty, and there's no <kbd>+</kbd> plus button for me to add an app, and I can't drag apps into the list. I think maybe this came up once before and I clicked Don't Allow. Now I can't get this prompt to come up again. How can I reset permissions so that the prompt comes back?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `tccutil` to manage the privacy database -- this involves opening the Terminal and using the command line! Here's how to do it for QuickTime Player:

```
tccutil reset Camera com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX
tccutil reset Microphone com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX
```

#### Other Applications

You might need to reset Camera or Microphone permissions for other apps too. If you know the [bundle ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39464668/190298) of the app you're trying to use, you can use this command:

```
tccutil reset Camera [com.WHATEVERBUNDLE.YOURAPPID]
tccutil reset Microphone [com.WHATEVERBUNDLE.YOURAPPID]
```

### Examples for Common Applications

*Safari*

```
tccutil reset Camera com.apple.Safari
tccutil reset Microphone com.apple.Safari
```

*Mozilla Firefox*

```
tccutil reset Camera org.mozilla.firefox
tccutil reset Microphone org.mozilla.firefox
```

*Google Chrome*

```
tccutil reset Camera com.google.Chrome
tccutil reset Microphone com.google.Chrome
```

*Slack*

```
tccutil reset Camera com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap
tccutil reset Microphone com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap
```

### The Nuclear Option

If you're running macOS Mojave (10.14) or if you just don't know the app bundle ID, then you'll need to reset Camera and Microphone permissions for all applications. This will remove any other apps that have been granted permission in the past, so you'll get prompted again by other apps.

```
tccutil reset Camera
tccutil reset Microphone
```

Once you've reset the camera and microphone permissions, you **must** quit your application before the change will take effect. Then you can restart your app and try using camera or microphone again, and the prompt should reappear.

[image]

**Help, it's still not working!**

Make sure that System Integrity Protection is enabled, otherwise these commands won't work correctly. To check, you can run `csrutil status` and it should say `System Integrity Protection status: enabled`.

Comment: Here is a [full list of known services](https://www.macblog.org/post/reset-tcc-privacy/) that tccutil can reset.

Comment: I heard from one person that they got `tccutil: No such bundle identifier` when trying to reset camera permissions for Slack, and had to use the nuclear option instead.

Comment: what if it still doesn't prompt after the nuclear option? the app is skype for business.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try dragging ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC to the trash bin and reboot. All of these steps, plus that one, worked for me.

Comment: I have two macs that constantly get this problem. Simple rebooting solves it in 9/10 cases for a few days again. Has anyone an idea why? It's a bit stressing if you want to get in a meeting and first need to reboot the machine… 

Answer (score 0):

From [Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204063) :

> If you're not using a Mac with Apple silicon, you're using an Intel-based Mac.
>
> #### How to reset NVRAM
>
> [image: Keyboard shortcut representation]
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Turn on your Mac, then press and hold these four keys together immediately: Option, Command, P, R.
> 3. Release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac may appear to restart. For example, you may hear a startup sound more than once, or see the Apple logo more than once.
> 4. When your Mac has finished starting up, you may need to adjust any system settings that have been reset.

This worked perfectly for me, I was having the same problem with my 2018 15" MacBook Pro. None of the apps were working or asking for permission to add the mic and camera permissions.

Comment: It’s much more likely that the reboot that happened  during this process is what fixed it.  There’s nothing in NVRAM related to mic and camera permissions.  See [this Meta post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3715/119271)

Comment: It is preferable to link to the question and put the relevant information into a blockquote. Posting a picture makes it difficult for future users to find the information since the picture doesn't have actual text.

Comment: Although the original image could have been from [here](https://purplecomputing.com/tech-how-to/how-to-reset-nvram-or-pram/), I've included the steps to be taken from the official Apple Support article (which is also the source of the above article). I have also included that this is how to do for Intel-based Macs (as per the Apple Support article). *All of this is in form of a suggested edit so it will apply if it gets accepted - it's now for reviewers to decide. ;)

Comment: Hey @Redarm , when opening the link, you would fall on a highlighted text (which is actually the title from what is quoted in the answer), I think it's better to keep that so that users can find the passage easily. Also, what I added is the *exact* quote from the Apple Support article; I think you should mention that the quote was edited.

Comment: @Thinkr The link did not specify a target on the page, but was localised to GB, which is all I took out.  You are right about the quote, even though other Mac processors do exist.

Comment: @Redarm Yeah, alright. ;)