# GotoMeeting says Microphone is Off though it is enabled in Sound

Tags: audio, microphone

The Sound app says that my BH20 Headset is connected and we can see a (low) level registering:

[image]

However the Google Meetup says the Microphone is off:

[image]

What am I missing on the Google Meetup settings?

**Update** In a comment @Tetsujin has pointed the way to the cause:

> Check System *Prefs > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Microphone*.

And in fact the Google Meet is not there - so he is correct:

[image]

I saw from this reference that it should be enabled by enabling
Chrome    But Chrome *is* already enabled ..

[image]

[image]

[image]

So now I do not know how to proceed to get the microphone acccess..

Comment: Check System Prefs > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Microphone.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ur right!  I'm not sure how to "add"  `Google Meet` to the permission list .. ?   I created an answer referencing your comment: pls feel free to create an answer that contains the same info and I can award to you.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384310/85275 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384317/85275