# How to enable privacy requirement for apps myself

Tags: audio, privacy, microphone

My zoom mic stops working this morning and it turns out that there is a new privacy requirement from my new Mac OS (that I just upgraded today) for Zoom, for both of its mic and camera usage.

[image]
However, the problem is Zoom says there is such new privacy requirement, and prompts me to go to the Privacy Settings, but having tried that many many times, my privacy requirement for both mic and camera usage are still blank.

[image]

I've already restarted my MBP.

Now my zoom is not working as expected.

```
ProductName:       Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H512
```

It was OK when the BuildVersion was `19H2`.

**UPDATE:**

Giving the situation that zoom knows and prompts me to change that privacy setting, I have a feeling that the problem is the incompatibility between zoom and my new Mac OS. And now I can proof it, because I just found out that my mic is not only not working for zoom, but it is also not working for my MS Team too, while they both worked perfectly yesterday.  Zoom at least knows and prompts me to change that privacy setting; whereas MS Team doesn't even realize the situation and never prompts me anything, just gives up working.

So, this is not a zoom problem any more, but New Mac OS problem, with all my apps, even for Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome, when visiting [screenapp.io](https://screenapp.io/beta/#/recording).

**UPDATE 2:**

Following up on [How do I reset Camera and Microphone permission on macOS Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384317/), here is my situation:

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.

$ tccutil reset Camera
tccutil: Failed to reset Camera

$ tccutil reset Microphone
tccutil: Failed to reset Microphone

$ sudo tccutil reset Microphone
tccutil: Failed to reset Microphone
```

Is there any way I can fix it myself?

Comment: what if you drag the zoom.app into that window for both Microphone and Camera?

Comment: No @SteveChambers, dragging the zoom.us from the app folder into that (unlocked) window for both Microphone and Camera doesn't work. It'll fly back.

Comment: Delete and reinstall Zoom?

Comment: I'm very new to Mac, as you can see that this is a basic how to enable something for some app kind of noob question. I really don't want go through that route unless absolutely necessary, just in fear it might mess up my system even further. Moreover, giving the situation that zoom knows and prompts me to change that privacy setting, I have a feeling that the problem is the incompatibility between zoom and my new Mac OS. I.e., redoing the installation won't help, IMHO.

Comment: Actually @xpt 's suggestion may be the right one as all you are doing is trashing the app bundle in the /Applications folder. Which *may* cause Zoom to request access to the mic/camera. You may also want to ask Zoom tech support (or if they have a tech forum) for their suggestions. If you get one that works you **can** answer your own questions here and it might be helpful for others.

Comment: Just found out that my mic is not only not working for zoom, but it is also not working for my MS Team too. So, this is not a zoom problem, but New Mac OS problem. Will change the title...

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384317/how-do-i-reset-camera-and-microphone-permission-on-macos-mojave  and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384310/how-do-i-configure-camera-and-microphone-permission-on-macos-mojave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ tccutil reset Camera
tccutil: Failed to reset Camera
```

Just realized that it has nothing to do with the OS update, because of the above failure, as I realized that I had changed my HOME folder. Right after having changed it back the problem is solved.

Sorry & Thanks everyone!