# Grant missing application permission to microphone and camera in macOS

Tags: macos, audio, system-settings, camera, firefox

I have installed Firefox (version 90.0.2) on macOS version 11.5.1.
In the Camera and Microphone panes under the Privacy tab in [Security & Privacy](https://support.apple.com/en-il/guide/mac-help/mh32356) settings, Firefox is missing.

I tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384318/337426) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384311/337426), then opened Firefox and navigated to a website that [prompted for using the cam and mic](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-manage-your-camera-and-microphone-permissions).

[image: firefox perms propmt]

Yet, when I approved it on Firefox, the Mac privacy dialog did not pop.

How can I give permissions to Firefox for microphone and camera to be able to use them in Firefox? (should it be [by modifying the privacy database?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119373))

(my System Integrity Protection status is enabled)